Cross-Compiling Qt Application with Log4Qt for BeagleBone Black: Compilation Issues
I'm working on a project where I'm cross-compiling a Qt application for the BeagleBone Black (BBB) using Ubuntu 20.04. I've integrated Log4Qt into my project but am encountering issues during the build process.
Setup Details:

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Cross-Compiler: GCC Linaro 7.5.0 (using sysroot 2.25, all folders located in my home directory)
Target Platform: BeagleBone Black (BBB)

Issue:
When attempting to build my project that uses Log4Qt, I’m encountering this error message:
/home/userProfile/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/Log4Qt/src/log4qt/helpers/initialisationhelper.h:24: error: log4qt/log4qtdefs.h: No such file or directory 
I’ve verified that Log4Qt is correctly configured and the required libraries are present, but I’m still facing problems.
Has anyone experienced similar issues or have suggestions on how to resolve them?
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Cleaned and rebuilt the project
Attempted static linking
Updated the project’s .pro file with the following changes:

include(/home/imesp21/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/Log4Qt/src/log4qt/log4qt.pri)

QT += network core
QT += sql concurrent

SOURCES += \
        loggermodule.cpp \
        mqttloggerbridge.cpp \
        main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /include
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -llog4qt

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    mqttloggerbridge.h \
    loggermodule.h

when I try to build, I get the error message about there isn't such a file or directory.
/home/userProfile/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/Log4Qt/src/log4qt/helpers/initialisationhelper.h:24: error: log4qt/log4qtdefs.h: No such file or directory

I solved this issue by changing
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -llog4qt

to
LIBS += -L/absolute/path/of/sysroot/usr/lib -llog4qt

